# Different versions of extensions running concurrently

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox

Is it possible to run **concurrently** two versions of an extension in an OSGi application with an extension point?

This is what I would like to accomplish:
I have an extension point Foo and a module with symbolic name Bar and version 1.0.0 plugged to the extension point and running (i.e. instantiated) in module A and module B. Then I install a new extension bundle with a bug fix, *symbolicName* Bar and version 1.0.1. and I want to run this new version only in module B, so module A still uses Bar v1.0.0 and module B uses now Bar v1.0.1.

From what I have seen, it is not possible since an extension needs to be a singleton so there can't be two versions of the same symbolic name. So our current solution is to have the symbolic name contain the version as well: *symbolicName* Bar_1_0_0 and *symbolicName* Bar_1_0_1. Doing this we can run each version in each module independently and concurrently since they are technically unrelated bundles that just happen to plug into the same extension point.

However, putting the version in the symbolic name seems like the wrong way to do it. Can this be accomplished without changing the symbolic name? am I missing something?

Comment: "they are technically unrelated bundles"... well no they're not, they are two versions of the same bundle.

Comment: @Neil  since they have different symbolic names how can osgi possibly know that they contain the same code, just different versions? the only difference between two really unrelated bundles is their symbolic name, so if two exact copies of a bundle have two different symbolic name, how can osgi know?

Comment: You're right, OSGi sees them as different bundles. I just think it's a stretch to call them "unrelated" since they are actually the same, other than the BSN.

Comment: i called them **technically** unrelated ;)  

Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't missing anything. Eclipse extension system (plugin.xml) only works with singleton bundles, which means multiple versions cannot be active at the same time. To have non-singleton extensions, you'd have to use a different extension system. I understand that OSGi services can handle this scenario. May want to take a look at the OSGi spec.

Comment: I agree, left out Eclipse extension points and use pure OSGi services